# Does silverlight really solve browser compatibility issues?

Tags: silverlight, web

I'm planning web application and considering silverlight as development platform. Will it help to solve browser compatibility issues? The app intended to be used on desktops only (no mobile).

Comment: yeah it will solve browser compatibility issues, but your client has to install silverlight client to work in your application.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it will solve browser compatibility issues, and could work on both Mac OS and Windows with the very same code.

The only drawback is that, the first time your user connect to your application, he will need to download the Silverlight plugin.

Awesome you would say? Well, unfortunately some people that probably never try to do something like image processing or advanced line of business application in a browser decide that plugins are not so cool and that you would be able to do the same thing with the magic power of HTML5.

We are still waiting to have the same possibility in HTML5 that we have in Silverlight or Flash, but plugins are already dead. At least as long as no big compay want to push them again.

So, my advice would be: don't start a project in Silverlight. You will have problems, even if you do not target mobile. For example it becomes harder and harder to find compatible good tools (like [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/), [NCrunch](http://www.ncrunch.net/), or even just a decent unit testing library). And in further release of Windows and Mac OS, it will probably not be supported at all (IE for Windows RT already does not support Silverlight).

Sorry man, [Silverlight is dead](http://community.spiceworks.com/topic/312391-silverlight-is-dead), you arrive after the battle.

Answer (score 2):

If your developing your application for an **Intranet**, I would say Silverlight is an excellent choice.

If you are developing for the **Internet**, use an HTML based language